# Not able to proceed with question on Stack Overflow

Tags: support

I want to post a question on Stack Overflow regarding a programming issue using VB.NET, but I am not able to click proceed after searching thoroughly and accepting keeping the tips in mind.

Is my account not activated yet? Or am I just not allowed to post a question?

Comment: Are you getting any messages? Popups?

Comment: No no pop-ups or messages. The "proceed" button is just grayed out. I looked for restrictions in my browser but none seem to be causing this

Comment: Strange... have you tried different browsers, or even different computers?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Show us your title and question text here.

Comment: No need to add "SOLVED" to your title, simply accept the answer

Comment: Cannot accept my own answer for 2 days it says. Thought this to be a good alternative

Comment: No need. You can accept your answer when it allows and in the meantime you may get a better answer as to *why* it wasn't working

Comment: Still would like to know the _why_ indeed. That might be helpfull for others.

Comment: Not able to _proceed_ when using Inet explorer 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @S.L. Barth

I was using Internet Explorer which did not allow me to proceed.
After Barth's comment I used Google Chrome and with that I am allowed to proceed.
Thanks.